# Endpoint of JSONP webservice not found even though registered in web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, web-services, jsonp

I have just added a new webservice, but when I approach it, I get: `Endpoint not found.`
on URL  `http://www.testsite.com/service.svc/getcompanyreviewdetails/?id=315&t=1`

I have another service where the endpoint IS found:
`http://www.testsite.com/service.svc/getshopitems/?newurl=myurl`

When I request `http://www.testsite.com/service.svc?wsdl`, I also don't see the `getcompanyreviewdetails` method in that list.

Here's my code:

**Iservice.vb**

```
Namespace RestService

    <ServiceContract()>
    Public Interface Icompanyservice

        <OperationContract()> _
<Web.WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, _
UriTemplate:="getcompanyreviewdetails/?id={id}&t={t}")> _
        Function getCompanyReviewDetails(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal t As Integer) As Stream
    End Interface

    <ServiceContract()>
    Public Interface Iservice
            <OperationContract()> _
    <Web.WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, _
    UriTemplate:="getshopitems/?newurl={newurl}")> _
            Function getShopItems(ByVal newURL As String) As Stream
    End Interface

End Namespace
```

**service.svc.vb**

```
Namespace RestService

<ServiceContract(Namespace:="RestService")>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)> _
Public Class companyservice
    Implements Icompanyservice

         Public Function getCompanyReviewDetails(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal t As Integer) As Stream Implements Icompanyservice.getCompanyReviewDetails
         End Function

    End Class

    <AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)> _
    Public Class service
        Implements Iservice 

        Public Function getShopItems(ByVal newURL As String) As Stream Implements Iservice.getShopItems
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

when adding a service reference I don't see the companyservice

[image: when adding a service reference I don't see the companyservice]

solution explorer

[image: solution explorer]

**web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>     
<client/>
<services>      
  <service name="RestService.service">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.Iservice" />
  </service>     
  <service name="RestService.companyservice">
    <endpoint address="http://www.testsite.com/service.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="RestService.Icompanyservice" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
  </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>        
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**UPDATE: configuring 2 endpoints**

```
<client>
  <endpoint name="basic" address="http://www.testsite.com/service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="RestService.Iservice" />      
</client>
<services>
  <service name="RestService.service" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"> <!-- in this case the property behaviorConfiguration is incorrect according to its datattype serviceBehaviorConfigurationType, I don't know what other value to provide here -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="RestService.Iservice" />
  </service>   
</services>
```

I then tried:

```
<client />
<services>
  <service name="RestService.service">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.Iservice" />
    <endpoint address="http://www.testsite.com/service.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="RestService.Icompanyservice" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The contract name 'RestService.Icompanyservice' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'service'.

So I tried moving all method of Icompanyservice under Iservice again and remove everything related to Icompanyservice. Also changed the web.config to:

```
  <service name="RestService.service">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.Iservice" />
    <endpoint address="http://www.testsite.com/service.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="RestService.Iservice" />
  </service>
```

I then got:

`When 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' is set to true in configuration, the endpoints are required to specify a relative address. If you are specifying a relative listen URI on the endpoint, then the address can be absolute. To fix this problem, specify a relative uri for endpoint 'http://www.testsite.com/service.svc'.`

So I set it to:

```
<endpoint address="/service.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="RestService.Iservice" />
```

Then both services work, but how can I validate if service `getcompanyreviewdetails` is now JSONP instead of JSON?

Comment: what happens if you change to Servicecontract instead of operationcontract for getcompanyreviewdetails

Comment: When changed to         <Servicecontract()> _
<Web.WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, _
UriTemplate:="getcompanyreviewdetails/?id={id}&t={t}")> _
        Function getCompanyReviewDetails(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal t As Integer) As Stream
    End Interface,  I get the design time error `Attribute 'ServiceContractAttribute' cannot be applied to 'getCompanyReviewDetails' because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Example.svc.vb` no interface.

```
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="{namespace the service resides in}")>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class ExampleService
```

Then adorn your methods in here as you would `<OperationalContract>MethodName`...

`ServiceReference.ClientConfig` - I have 2 endpoints one for testing local and the other for publish - remember to comment out one or the other depending on what your doing(publishing vs testing).

```
<endpoint address="http://{your domain}/ExampleService.svc"
 binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ExampleService"
 contract="ExampleServRef.ExampleService" name="CustomBinding_ExampleService" />

<endpoint address="http://{localhost:port}/ExampleService.svc"
 binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ExampleService"
 contract="ExampleServRef.ExampleService" name="CustomBinding_ExampleService" />
```

[A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)

[WCF Multiple Endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I've added `<ServiceContract(Namespace:="")>` to weddingservice.svc.vb file, but I'm unsure what to place in my web.config file based on your example. What values should I provide for properties `binding`, `bindingConfiguration`, `contract` and `name`? Thanks

Comment: You define the name in the `<Binding>` element then use that name in the `<EndPoint>` element.

Comment: I added `<webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>` and added `webHttpBindingWithJsonP` for the `binding` property, but what about the other properties?

Comment: Does the `name` attribute match the `Binding` name and `binding` attribute match the binding type?

Comment: I've updated my post with your suggestions and my new questions

Comment: Since your service is in a namespace - `<ServiceContract(Namespace:="RestService")>`

Comment: Some great info in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx).

Comment: I've looked at your link and updated my entire post with latest configuration, but still I get the error `endpoint not found` :(

Comment: Try just the second address in your services.

Comment: You mean this url from my service section? `http://www.testsite.com/weddingservice.svc`, because all I get then is a `You have created a service.` page. Or what address are you refering to? ps. sorry for my many questions, this is new terrain for me :)

Comment: You have two `endpoints` I was just wondering if you comment out one or the other to see which one works, you should have only one in here.

Comment: But I need 2 endpoints right? Because 1 service is with jsonp and the other is just regular json. When combining it into 1 endpoint I wouldn't know how to support both json and jsonp.

Comment: [WCF Multiple Endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm a further now, see updated post. How can I validate if the service is now offering jsonp?